# How to validate XML in .NET Core 1.1.2

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, coreclr, system.xml

How can i validate XML against XSD schema in .NET Core 1.1.2? i found this [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset) but i cannot use it with .NET core 1.1.2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class XmlValidation
    {   

        public static void Validate(string schema, string xml)
        {
            XmlReaderSettings schemaSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            schemaSettings.Schemas.Add(schema);
            schemaSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            schemaSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xml, schemaSettings);
            while (reader.Read()) { }
        }

        static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting errors

> The type or namespace name 'ValidationEventHandler' could not be found
>   The type or namespace name 'ValidationEventArgs' could not be found
>   The name 'ValidationType' does not exist in the current context   Domain
>      'XmlReaderSettings' does not contain a definition for 'Schemas' and
>   no extension method 'Schemas' accepting a first argument of type
>   'XmlReaderSettings' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

am i missing any Nuget Package here or .NET Core 1.1 does not even support xml validation?

Answer (score 1):

It does not. [Here is the XmlReaderSettings class in .NET Core 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings?view=netcore-1.1). There are is no `ValidationEventHandler` under `Events`. [Here is the same class in .NET Core 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings?view=netcore-2.0) where it is present.

Comment: So how do we validate Xml in .net core 1.1.2?

Comment: @LP13: why don't you upgrade to .Net core 2.0?. Upgrading from .Net core 1.1.2 to 2.0 is really simple

Comment: thats what i ended up doing.